# instruction on how to compile using sassy studio in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, compilation, sass

I have been using Compass to compile sass files in Windows environment either on a command line or using Compass-app to watch a directory.

I've just started using Visual Studio (pro 2013).  I have installed sassy studio using nuget but I can not find any instructions as to how to compile.

It looks like sasssy studio comes with its own sass compiler or it can use Compass.  I've looked at the setting menu but nothing seems obvious as to how to compile to CSS automatically on save or even doing it manually.

1) Does the set up require a config.rb file or is there a different way to set up the configuration (such as 'require' options)?

2) How does one initiate the compile operation either automatically or manually?

TIA

Comment: I think you should look into MSBuild

Comment: @user2872191 Once you set the ruby path it is automatically enabled on projects that have config.rb and will automatically compile on save.

Comment: Thank you Darren.  I added a config.rb and set the ruby path to 'c:\ruby193' directory instead of 'C:\ruby193\bin'.  Now it's compiling on save.  Intellisense seems to be working okay so far.

Comment: Darren, if I leave 'Compile on Save' option off, is there a way to force a compilation when I want to compile?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same trouble, so I followed this guide for [Integrating the Compass CSS Framework into Visual Studio](http://thedevstop.wordpress.com/2012/01/08/integrating-the-compass-css-framework-into-visual-studio/). I installed Ruby and Compass and then added the path to the Ruby folder in the SassyStudio options.

I was originally using Web Workbench so my Visual Studio project was already set up as a Compass project (had a config.rb file).  So now it compiles correctly when I save.

I don't know whether this is necessarily the correct way, but it worked for me.

Comment: Thank you for the link.  I used the instruction on the link page to set up an additional 'Create Compass Project' command button.  Since Sass-Studio is compiling automatically on save, I did not need to set up the 'Watch' command button.